# passing template for later use in other struct/class context

Tags: c++, using

I have some classes which need to define a template which can be used in generic code parts as type later.

In real world code the forwarded templates have a lot more parameters and it is not really nice to read the code.

Q: Is it possible to define the template in some syntax instead of writing it as alias template as given in the following example? I simple would avoid repeating of all the template parameters two times of each alias declaration.

The real world template also have some non type template parameters so simply using `<PARMS...>` will not work.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

template < typename T>
struct A
{
    static void Do(T t) { std::cout << "A " << t << std::endl;}
};

template < typename T>
struct B
{
    static void Do(T t) { std::cout << "B " << t << std::endl;}
};

struct UseA
{
    // using the alias template works as expected, but...
    template < typename T>
        using USE = A<T>;

    // is there any chance to write something like:
    // using USE = A; 
    // to simply avoid replication of template parameters?
};

struct UseB
{
    template < typename T>
        using USE = B<T>;
};

int main()
{
    UseA::USE<int>::Do(1);
    UseB::USE<std::string>::Do("Hallo");
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to achieve? This seems very contrived and impractical...

Comment: @jan.sende The app has data objects and is able to generate terms simply by writing `auto x= a+b;` a and b are that data objects. The generated term data type is dependent on the data types but the generator ( overloaded operator ) should not be specialized for each data type again. As this, the overloaded operator generates a term object of the type presented by the data objects. The full example is much to big to present it here. And its not really needed to understand what my current coding problem is. So I made that example which looks a bit useless.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking cannot be done. You always have to define the whole type list. The reason is, that one could have default overloads for the same type. For example, in the following `A<int, 3>`, `A<int>` and `A<>` are all valid. The compiler does not know which one you want:

```
template <class T, int Value = 42>
struct A {};

auto test() {
    auto a = A<int, 3>{};
    auto b = A<int>{};
    auto c = A<>{};
}
```

If you don't want to write the type lists, I would recommend you to switch to templatizing more of your classes, so they don't need to know about the implementation details. Like:

```
#include <iostream>

template < typename T>
struct A
{
    static void Do(T t) { std::cout << "A " << t << std::endl;}
};

template < typename T>
struct B
{
    static void Do(T t) { std::cout << "B " << t << std::endl;}
};

template < typename T>
struct Use
{
    using USE = T;
};

int main()
{
    Use<A<int>>::USE::Do(1);
    Use<B<std::string>>::USE::Do("Hallo");
}
```

Or alternatively, use containers for your non template type values:

```
#include <iostream>

template < int Value >
struct INT
{
    static constexpr int value = Value;
};
template < bool Value >
struct BOOL
{
    static constexpr bool value = Value;
};

template < typename T, typename Value >
struct A
{
    static void Do(T t) { std::cout << "A " << t << Value::value << std::endl;}
};

template < typename T, typename Value>
struct B
{
    static void Do(T t) { if (Value::value) std::cout << "B " << t << std::endl;}
};

template <template<typename...> class T, typename ...Param>
using USE = T<Param...>;

int main()
{
    USE<A, int, INT<42>>::Do(1);
    USE<B, std::string, BOOL<true>>::Do("Hallo");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your work. "I would recommend you to switch to templatizing more of your classes". Not possible, because the "user" of the template is the overloaded operator. I want to use the simple syntax `auto x=a+b` and this should be generic code part so the operator itself should "know" which type to generate based on the data objects a and b.

Comment: Additional remark: "You always have to define the whole type list. The reason is"... I want to forward the template and not the template instance/type. That is the core idea. You also can pass a template into another template and create an instance later. At the point I wrote the using, I did not want to create an instance! The instance is created at the place where the "forwarded" alias template is used.

Comment: I think we have a mental disconnect somewhere. What I here you saying is: I want an operator, which depending on the arguments does the right thing. For example, `"4"+"2"="42"`, but `4+2=6`. This is what overloading does. No templates required. You can use templates to make these operators more general, but then you have to templatize them. I guess you then run into problems with templates being too broad, but you can fix this with SFINEA,...

Comment: Furthermore, you say you want to pass the template, but `A` is not the template, `A<...>` is! Types without the `<>` are just normal types. Btw. it seems to me that you are trying to invent expression templates. Have a look at: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates

Comment: "but then you have to templatize them." Sorry, no! All my code works as expected, the only question is to simplify the alias template. The operator overloads are generic and there is no need to specialize them for every data type I want to use. Exactly that was the target of that design: "Make the operator code generic!" As this, the operator only needs the alias template to generate the new "Term" objects. NO specialization and no SFINAE and especially do not expose the Term type to the operators. This end up in maintenance nightmare. Every Term type with own overload/specialization. No! :-)

Comment: If you have such specific needs, please put them in the question. Anyways, I answered your question. It is not possible to alias the template the way you want. You always have to give the whole type list because the template name and the parameter list are the template. The template name on its own does not have any meaning.